# how to enable isPaging of scroll view in swiftUI and make the infinite scroll

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have implemented scroll view in swiftUI and I want to enable paging functionality like collectionView, if we scroll our scroll view it will scroll to next element and one element have take full screen, here is my code

```
 var textScrollView: some View {
 ScrollView {
     VStack(spacing: 20) {
         ForEach(0..<self.textData.count, id: \.self) { index in
             
             let text = (AppData.shared().appFont == "ScopeOne-Regular") && (textData[index].text.hasSuffix("!")) ? "\u{2800}\(textData[index].text)\u{2800}" : " \(textData[index].text) "
             
             Text(text)
                 .foregroundColor(.white)
                 .font(.largeTitle)
                 .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                 .padding()
                 .frame(width : UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height,alignment: .center)
                 
         }
     }
 }
 .frame(width : UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height,alignment: .center)
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by **enable isPaging**? In order to do **infinite scroll** you would need to get the current index and if you reached a certain threashold pull the next batch of items. Read [this](https://medium.com/whatnot-engineering/the-next-page-8950875d927a) article on how it could be achieved.

Comment: isPagging means if i scroll the content it should move to next item.